# How do I configure the "Build Periodically" build trigger via jenkins job builder?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-builder

I have a jenkins job currently and I'm trying to set it to run every 4 hours via a jjb. I've configured it to run every 4 hours currently by manually editing the job and selecting the "Build Periodically" trigger and entering in the appropriate value. However, i'd like to find a way to automate this process. I've looked through the documentation here: `https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/jenkins-job-builder/latest/jenkins-job-builder.pdf` but I haven't had any luck.

This is what I have currently:

`- 'build-job-jjb-{type}-{label}':
          type: build
          label: Build
          git_repo: XXXXXXX
          git_url: git@github.com:XXXXXXXX/{git_repo}.git
          git_branch: origin/develop
          home: pipeline/scripts
          cmd: ./build.sh
          triggers:
            - timed: "00 08,12,16,20,00,04 * * *"`

Answer (score 5):

You are on the correct way, but you could set a shedule like:

```
-job:
    triggers:
      - timed: "0 */4 * * *"
```

This execute your job every 4 hours at minute 0.

If you want to let the server choose the minute when the load is low, you should set:

```
-job:
    triggers:
      - timed: "H */4 * * *"
```

This worked for me when i've created the job with jjb template .

I hope this help you!